# How can I use mutate to find the difference between two years in one column of my dataframe?

Tags: r, dplyr

Hi i am new to the tidyverse in R and trying to work on a project

My dataframe(ab):

```
 Year       Zip     Total_Population Median_Income      City State
1 2014      00601            18088         10833  Adjuntas    PR
2 2014      00602            40859         16353    Aguada    PR
3 2015      00603            53162         16323 Aguadilla    PR
4 2015      00606             6415         14138   Maricao    PR
5 2016      00610            28805         17265    Anasco    PR
6 2016      00612            66251         17752   Arecibo    PR
```

I have used mutate to create population to income ratio based on zip:

```
dmg_ratio <-  ab %>% filter(Year %in% c(2014,2015,2016,2017)) %>% 
  group_by(Zip) %>%
  mutate(Poptoincomeratio = Total_Population/Median_Income)

dmg_ratio
```

Output repex:

```
Year Zip           Total_Population Median_Income City      State Poptoincomeratio
 2014 ZCTA5 00601            18088         10833 Adjuntas    PR               1.67 
 2014 ZCTA5 00602            40859         16353 Aguada      PR               2.50 
 2015 ZCTA5 00601            53162         16323 Adjuntas    PR               3.26
```

I want to find the difference in this newly created mutation(Poptoincomeratio) from 2014 to 2016 per zip code to understand if there has been any change in the population to income ratio over the years.
How would I be able to do this?

Comment: How do you get your expected output? It looks like it's just first 3 rows of `dmg_ratio` ?

Comment: @RonakShah basically output i desire is lets say for zip code 00601 in 2014 the ratio is 1.67 and in year 2015 same zip has ratio 3.26. I want to get the difference. I have re edited my output repex for better clarity

Comment: something like `dmg_ratio %>%
  group_by(Zip) %>%
  arrange(Year) %>%
  mutate(difference = Poptoincomeratio - lag(Poptoincomeratio)) `  using `dplyr` ?

Comment: @RonakShah For some reason this returns NA's although that seems like the OP's intended output.

Comment: @NelsonGon it will because there is only row per `Zip` in the example shared so there is nothing to subtract but I am assuming this is only sample data which OP has shared and their actual data has lot many rows for every `Zip`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is a workaround for this, I assumed you have 'Poptoincomeratio' columns filled for every single year
Then, try this

```
library(tidyr)
new_ab <- ab %>% select(-Total_Population ,-Median_Income ) %>% spread(Year,Poptoincomeratio)
```

After this, you can apply mutate again to get the difference between two years.

Comment: why have you used -Total_Population ,-Median_Income the minus sign before these two elements? Im new to r and trying to understand the syntax

Comment: In select minus(-) refer to exclude the column with the minus sign, hence we're removing these two columns because there all observations are unique and if I use spread function without removing these columns, spread function wont work properly the way I want it to. I would recommend you to read the documentation and use of Spread and Gather function, it's may come in handy in the future.